# Find the most frequent k-mers with mismatches in a text

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am trying to solve finding the most frequent k-mers with mismatches in a string. The requirements are listed below:

Frequent Words with Mismatches Problem: Find the most frequent k-mers with mismatches in a string.

Input: A string Text as well as integers k and d. (You may assume k ≤ 12 and d ≤ 3.)

Output: All most frequent k-mers with up to d mismatches in Text.

Here is an example:

Sample Input:

ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT

4 1

Sample Output:

GATG ATGC ATGT

The simplest and most inefficient way is to list all of k-mers in the text and calculate their hamming_difference between each other and pick out patterns whose hamming_difference less than or equal with d, below is my code:

```
import collections

kmer = 4
in_genome = "ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT";
in_mistake = 1;
out_result = [];
mismatch_list = []

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    # Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    else:
        return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

for i in xrange(len(in_genome)-kmer + 1):
    v = in_genome[i:i + kmer]
    out_result.append(v)

for i in xrange(len(out_result) - 1):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(out_result)):
        if hamming_distance(str(out_result[i]), str(out_result[j])) <= in_mistake:
            mismatch_list.extend([out_result[i], out_result[j]])

mismatch_count = collections.Counter(mismatch_list)
print [key for key,val in mismatch_count.iteritems() if val == max(mismatch_count.values())]
```

Instead of the expected results, I got 'CATG'. Does anyone know something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all seems great until your last line of code:

```
print [key for key,val in mismatch_count.iteritems() if val == max(mismatch_count.values())]
```

Since CATG scored higher than any other kmer, you'll only ever get that one answer.  Take a look at:

```
>>> print mismatch_count.most_common()
[('CATG', 9), ('ATGA', 6), ('GCAT', 6), ('ATGC', 4), ('TGCA', 4), ('ATGT', 4), ('GATG', 4), ('GTTG', 2), ('TGAG', 2), ('TTGC', 2), ('CGCA', 2), ('TGAT', 1), ('GTCG', 1), ('AGAG', 1), ('ACGT', 1), ('TCGC', 1), ('GAGC', 1), ('GAGA', 1)]
```

to figure out what it is you really want back from this result.

I believe the fix is to change your second top level 'for' loop to read as follows:

```
for t_kmer in set(out_result):
    for s_kmer in out_result:
        if hamming_distance(t_kmer, s_kmer) <= in_mistake:
            mismatch_list.append(t_kmer)
```

This produces a result similar to what you're expecting:

```
>>> print mismatch_count.most_common()
[('ATGC', 5), ('ATGT', 5), ('GATG', 5), ('CATG', 4), ('ATGA', 4), ('GTTG', 3), ('CGCA', 3), ('GCAT', 3), ('TGAG', 3), ('TTGC', 3), ('TGCA', 3), ('TGAT', 2), ('GTCG', 2), ('AGAG', 2), ('ACGT', 2), ('TCGC', 2), ('GAGA', 2), ('GAGC', 2), ('TGTC', 1), ('CGTT', 1), ('AGCT', 1)]
```

Comment: @ cdlane It is look like below, 
'GATG' matches: AC'GTTG'CATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTG'CATG'TCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCG'CATG'ATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCGCAT'GATG'CATGAGAGCT ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATG'CATG'AGAGCT
'ATGC' matches: ACG'TTGC'ATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGC'ATGT'CGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCGC'ATGA'TGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCGCATG'ATGC'ATGAGAGCT ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGC'ATGA'GAGCT
'ATGT' matches: 'ACGT'TGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGC'ATGT'CGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCGC'ATGA'TGCATGAGAGCT, ACGTTGCATGTCGCATG'ATGC'ATGAGAGCT  ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGC'ATGA'GAGCT

Comment: @ cdlane  'GATG' ,'ATGC','ATGT', all of these k-mers has 5 approximate matches with the text which are considered as 'The most frequent k-mer with up to d (d = 1) mismatches'

Comment: @nosense I've added to my answer a modification of your last top level 'for' loop that I believe solves the problem.

Comment: Can you help me why my code does not work. It looks so similar to your newly updated code. And what is the purpose for using set() for the first "for" loop while not using for the nested one?

Comment: @ cdlane One more question, if we consider this situation like: "Note that Pattern does not need to actually appear as a substring of Text; for example, as we already saw, AAAAA is the most frequent 5-mer with 1 mismatch in 'AACAA'GCTG'ATAAA'CATTT'AAAGA'G, even though it does not appear exactly in this string. Keep this in mind while solving the following problem." How do I revise my code?

Comment: @nosense, my compact explanation of why your loop didn't work, consider the sequence ****CATG****CATG****GATG where we have CATG#1 and CATG#2  -- we scan it with CATG#1 and get two matches, then we scan it with CATG#2 and get another match but then combine those results regardless of whether they came from CATG#1 or #2 so we end up with an over count.  The set() in my solution says give me the *unique* kmers which we then compare against all the kmers.  I tried tweaking your loop by adjusting various clauses to get it to work but I gave up and rewrote it into the one I added to my answer.

Comment: @nosense, the answer to the 'AAAAA' question is easy, instead of initializing out_result to an empty list, initialize it with any kmers you explicitly want to test:  `out_result = ["AAAAA"]`